# python multiprocessing Lock and Queue not working on an older Linux kernel

Tags: python-3.x, linux, locking, posix, yocto

I have a real time machine running linux 32bit with kernel 4.9.124-rt94-rc1-mx6-sr+g79f5711 built with the Yocto Project. And a second, older machine running 32bit linux with 3.18.48-rt54-yocto-standard kernel, also created with the Yocto Project.

I have 2 short python scripts.
the first:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Lock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flag_lock = Lock()
     
    flag_lock.acquire()
    flag_lock.release()
```

And the second:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = mp.Queue()
    print("hello")
    test.put(3)
    print("world")
```

Both of this scripts run just fine on the newer machine with the 4.9.124-rt94-rc1-mx6-sr+g79f5711 kernel

Executing the first script on the machine with the older kernel will throw an exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./temp_lock.py", line 8, in 
flag_lock.release()
ValueError: semaphore or lock released too many times

Executing the second script on the machine with the older kernel will print the "hello" and will get stuck indefinitely on the test.put(3).

Considering the queue is thread safe I assume some locking mechanism in it fails.

I used python 3.6.0 and python 3.8.3 to execute this scripts with same results on both of the machines.

I used strace on the first script(the one with the lock) and the main difference I found is that on the older machine
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0xbfe94f4c)            = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device) keeps failing 57 times.

I also noticed that the fstat64() is called, from this I conclude that the implantation of the locks in multiprocessing module is POSIX

Answer (score 0):

I replaced multiprocessing library with threading library and now all the issues with locking and queue are solved and the code executes on the older kernel the same way it does on the newer one.

I still can't explain what makes the difference under the hood and why multiprocessing.Queue and multiprocessing.Lock works just fine on the newer kernel but not on the older one.